# Inconsistent behavior when referencing constants inside a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, module, scope, constants

In my Rails 3.2 models directory, I have a folder "foo" containing two classes:

```
# foo/bar.rb
class Foo::Bar; end

# foo/baz.rb
class Foo::Baz
  def self.test
    puts Bar.to_s
  end
end
```

Note that Foo::Baz.test references Foo::Bar as simply Bar, since Bar and Baz are in the same module.

I then open the console and call Foo::Baz.test twice:

```
1.9.3-p0 :001 > Foo::Baz.test
Foo::Bar
 => nil 
1.9.3-p0 :002 > Foo::Baz.test
NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Baz::Bar
    from /../app/models/foo/baz.rb:2:in `test'
```

As you can see, the call works fine the first time, and then crashes every time thereafter.  Why?

This does **not** happen if Foo::Baz uses the fully qualified name Foo::Bar instead of just Bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to work if you declare the module separately:

```
# foo/bar.rb
module Foo
  class Bar; end
end

# foo/baz.rb
module Foo
  class Baz
    def self.test
      puts Bar.to_s
    end
  end
end

$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
1.9.3-p125 :001 > Foo::Baz.test
Foo::Bar
 => nil 
1.9.3-p125 :002 > Foo::Baz.test
Foo::Bar
 => nil 
1.9.3-p125 :003 >
```

I cannot explain why.

Comment: That's interesting.  Do you know of other functional differences between explicitly declaring `module Foo` and just prefixing with `Foo::`?

edit: found some possible clues: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/145121

Comment: @rcrogers Not that I know of.  It looks like this behavior is specific to rails.

Comment: It looks like there was a related bug report a while back: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/1422