# How to build a failing test? Test passes but Rails server says: ‘uninitialized constant’

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

This may be a similar issue to “[Inconsistent behavior when referencing constants inside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179737/inconsistent-behavior-when-referencing-constants-inside-a-module)”, but I am not sure.

I am in a situation where my test works but my app fails, and while I can fix the app, I would rather have a test which fails if the app does!

Here’s the basic setup:

**admin_controller.rb** (like ApplicationController, other controllers inherit)

```
class AdminController < ActionController::Base

  # If a session_grouping is set, it should be used until unset.
  def session_grouping
    session[:default_grouping] || DraftGrouping.new
  end

  ...

end
```

**admin_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'
class AdminControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def test_get_session_grouping
    assert_equal DraftGrouping, @controller.session_grouping.class, 'without a grouping set, a draft grouping should be returned'
  end

  ...

end
```

This test (and the other tests which I have excluded for clarity) all pass with `DraftGrouping` defined as follows:

**grouping.rb**

```
class Grouping < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

# Used as a stand-in for a real grouping until there is something to save.
class DraftGrouping

  # Any call to real_grouping instantiates the grouping in the database.
  def real_grouping
    @real_grouping || @real_grouping = Grouping.create!
  end

  ...

end
```

However, when used in the application, `AdminController#session_grouping` fails with the message `NameError (uninitialized constant AdminController::DraftGrouping): app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:5:in`session_grouping'`

I can fix all this by defining `DraftGrouping` inside `Grouping` and calling `Grouping::DraftGrouping` everywhere. Now actually that’s a clearer way of doing things anyway, so I’m happy to do it. But how should I have built a failing test for this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying `DraftGrouping` within `grouping.rb`? It looks like you may be from your code samples.

If so, it's possible that Rails' autoloading routines can't find it when it comes to trying to instantiate it in `admin_controller.rb`. Your tests might be passing if they have already referenced `Grouping` (and hence have already loaded grouping.rb and thus the definition for `DraftGrouping`).

The first thing I'd try is to move the definition for DraftGrouping to `draft_grouping.rb`.

Comment: Yep, that absolutely makes sense. I will give it a go.

Comment: My question then, though, is how the test managed to load `DraftGrouping`. Even running just that test in isolation passes, so I suppose the way **test_helper.rb** loads the environment must differ from the server in some way, which seems likely to introduce inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks for the input on this. Your approach fixes the error in the app, and has helped me understand the autoloading a bit better. However, my question really is how to build a failing test for this. My full-stack integration tests don’t fail on this either, so I’m at a loss as to how I could’ve caught this without manual testing.

Comment: My guess is that other tests instantiate `Grouping`, which then autoloads `grouping.rb` – and that in turn loads `DraftGrouping` into memory, so you don't hit the error (which I'll call "failure to autoload", although there's probably a more formal term) that occurs in production.  We use Rspec for our testing so I don't know about [`Test::Unit`'s random ordering setting](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/en/Test/Unit/TestCase.html#test_order=-class_method), but it's possible that running tests in a random order could help discover these sort of dependency issues.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. My tests are already randomised by Minitest, and this test run on its own passes. However I run tests through Zeus to cut down the boot time, so maybe the environment Zeus forks from hasn’t unloaded all the symbols from previous test runs.